# Better approach to do this for security and code management purpose

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am working on a Cakephp 2.3 on a  very big project and I'm about to launch my site worldwide.

I have a login system on my app. I am sharing my code because I want to make sure if I am coding right or not ... and also any check for any functions missing or if any advice of adding something or removing something in the code would be greatly appreciated. And also comment in security perspective too...
Do tell me some tips of making my website faster.. for example how to write faster queries or remove unwanted from this blabla

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public $components = array('Cookie');

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        App::uses('Utility', 'Utility');
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
        $this->Security->requireSecure('login'); // for security

        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Authenticate.Cookie' => array(
               'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
               ),
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'scope' => array(
                   'User.active' => 1
                )
            ),
            'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),
                'columns' => array(
                    'email',
                    'mobileNo'
                ),
                'userModel' => 'User'
            )
        );
    }



public function index()
{
    $this->layout = 'logindefault';

    if (!$this->Auth->login() || !$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {

        $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ));

    } else {
        $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ));
    }

}


public function login()
{

    $this->layout = 'logindefault';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Login');




    if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {


        $lastLogin = $this->Auth->User('lastLogin');

        if ($lastLogin != null) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'Userinfo',
                'action' => 'gettingstarted'
            ));

        }

    } else {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $mobileNo = $this->request->data['User']['email'];

            $mobileNo = Utility::addPlusToMobileNo($mobileNo);

            $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $mobileNo;




            if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
                if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')) {

                    $this->_setCookie($this->Auth->user('idUser'));

                    $lastLogin = $this->Auth->User('lastLogin');
                    if ($lastLogin != null) {
                        $this->redirect(array(
                            'controller' => 'users',
                            'action' => 'dashboard'
                        ));
                    } else {

                        $this->redirect(array(
                            'controller' => 'Userinfo',
                            'action' => 'gettingstarted'
                        ));

                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect Email/Password Combination'); 
            }
        }
    }
}



protected function _setCookie($id)
{
    if (!$this->request->data('User.remember_me')) {
        return false;
    }
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->request->data('User.email'),
        'password' => $this->request->data('User.password')
    );
    $this->Cookie->write('User', $data, true, '1 week');
    return true;
}


public function logout()
{
    $this->Cookie->delete('User');
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Looks like you're already using the [SecurityComponent](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-SecurityComponent.html) if you want to secure your app use it everywhere. For AJAX forms white list only the fields you need, dont disable the component!
- Put App::uses('Utility', 'Utility'); on top of the file
- $mobileNo = Utility::addPlusToMobileNo($mobileNo); should happen in the model beforeSave()
- If this is supposed to be used world wide I assume you want translations, this is missing the translation method call __() setFlash('Incorrect Email/Password Combination');
- Most of the code CAN and should go into the model layer
- Are there unit tests? If not add unit tests, specially test validation of data and false data input. You want ~85%+ Code Coverage for unit tests.
- You're not following the CakePHP coding standards

There is no way to tell you more than this without being able to access the whole app code and doing a code review (I could do that). For queries, always just query the data you need, check the generated SQL queries, use DebugKit to check the query times to find slow querys and slowly rendering pages.

Comment: @thankyou burzum .... i can post you the AppController if you say ... second i didnt get your fourth point .. i dont know about the method call..never heard of it... and the the 6th point about unit tests ... what does it mean.. can you give me an example .. and the last you are saying that i am not following the coding standards of cake .. how ?

Comment: and also you have said that put app uses on top of the file ... where ?? after class declaration.. class UsersController extends AppController{  App::uses('Utility', 'Utility');            but it gives me an error here

Comment: and do tell me that as i am downloading debug kit ... so i want to know when i make my website public should i have to delete the debug kit then ???